# Chromium semi freezing in a predictable way on very unclear reasons

Tags: display, chromium, kiosk, nodered, nginx

I have a Raspberry PI 3B+/raspbian running my NodeJS (node-red) backend application. My Raspberry is hosting a frontend application (VueJS) as well. I also have a 7" display connected. The purpose with the system is to display a map of 433 Mhz electrical switches in my home.

If I, for example, click on a switch on the display - the system should turn on/off the lamp and indicate the current state. This has been working flawless for months!
[image]
A picture of the display. A javascript clock i the lower right corner.

Since a few weeks, I am facing a really strange behaviour:

Sometimes between 06.30 - 06.33 (6.33 AM) every day, something (??) happens and the browser seems to be non responsive on my 7" display. One thing that is strange is that I am able to move the cursor when touching display. Nothing obviously happens when I click on a button, BUT!, since I have started my Chromium instance like this: `chromium-browser --disable-gpu --remote-debugging-port=9222 --remote-debugging-address==10.0.0.4 --user-data-dir=remote-profile --kiosk http://localhost/kommandoran2.0/#/` (in `/etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart`) I am able to remote debug. I can see that correct javascripts are invoked when I click on buttons (in the real world, my switches turns on and off). The problem is that the GUI seems to be semi frozen. At least the GUI in Chrome/KIOSK. The GUI is not updating itself in Chrome

This is the inspector from a Chrome instance on a windows computer in my network when my Pi has been "frozen"
[image]

Ok, some javascript errors, but they are indicating other things.

Since I am the "developer", I am very sure that I have nothing in either backend (node-red) or frontend (VueJS) which should be able to cause this behavior!

Here are some example output from `journalctl` from my Raspberry:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ journalctl --since "2019-08-13 06:00:00"        
Aug 13 6:09:01      raspberrypi CRON[20587]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Aug 13 6:09:01      raspberrypi CRON[20592]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php/sessionclean ] && if [ ! -d /run/systemd/system ]; then /usr/lib/php/sessionclea
Aug 13 6:09:01      raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Clean php session files...
Aug 13 6:09:01      raspberrypi CRON[20587]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Aug 13 6:09:01      raspberrypi systemd[1]: phpsessionclean.service: Succeeded.
Aug 13 6:09:01      raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Clean php session files.
Aug 13 6:17:01      raspberrypi CRON[24891]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Aug 13 6:17:01      raspberrypi CRON[24895]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Aug 13 6:17:01      raspberrypi CRON[24891]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Aug 13 6:25:01      raspberrypi CRON[29156]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Aug 13 6:25:01      raspberrypi CRON[29160]: (root) CMD (test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily ))
Aug 13 6:25:02      raspberrypi CRON[29156]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Aug 13 6:30:02      raspberrypi rngd[320]: stats: bits received from HRNG source: 260064
Aug 13 6:30:02      raspberrypi rngd[320]: stats: bits sent to kernel pool: 213824
Aug 13 6:30:02      raspberrypi rngd[320]: stats: entropy added to kernel pool: 213824
Aug 13 6:30:02      raspberrypi rngd[320]: stats: FIPS 140-2 successes: 13
Aug 13 6:30:02      raspberrypi rngd[320]: stats: FIPS 140-2 failures: 0
Aug 13 6:30:02      raspberrypi rngd[320]: stats: FIPS 140-2(2001-10-10) Monobit: 0
Aug 13 6:30:02      raspberrypi rngd[320]: stats: FIPS 140-2(2001-10-10) Poker: 0
Aug 13 6:30:02      raspberrypi rngd[320]: stats: FIPS 140-2(2001-10-10) Runs: 0
Aug 13 6:30:02      raspberrypi rngd[320]: stats: FIPS 140-2(2001-10-10) Long run: 0
Aug 13 6:30:02      raspberrypi rngd[320]: stats: FIPS 140-2(2001-10-10) Continuous run: 0
Aug 13 6:30:02      raspberrypi rngd[320]: stats: HRNG source speed: (min=422.800; avg=940.174; max=1173.753)Kibits/s
Aug 13 6:30:02      raspberrypi rngd[320]: stats: FIPS tests speed: (min=5.320; avg=9.536; max=16.542)Mibits/s
Aug 13 6:30:02      raspberrypi rngd[320]: stats: Lowest ready-buffers level: 2
Aug 13 6:30:02      raspberrypi rngd[320]: stats: Entropy starvations: 0
Aug 13 6:30:02      raspberrypi rngd[320]: stats: Time spent starving for entropy: (min=0; avg=0.000; max=0)us
******* 06:32 FREEZE
Aug 13 6:34:19      raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Daily apt upgrade and clean activities...
Aug 13 6:34:23      raspberrypi systemd[1]: apt-daily-upgrade.service: Succeeded.
Aug 13 6:34:23      raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Daily apt upgrade and clean activities.
Aug 13 6:39:01      raspberrypi CRON[4436]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Aug 13 6:39:01      raspberrypi CRON[4442]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php/sessionclean ] && if [ ! -d /run/systemd/system ]; then /usr/lib/php/sessionclean
Aug 13 6:39:01      raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Clean php session files...
...

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ journalctl --since "2019-08-14 06:00:00"     
Aug 14 6:09:01      raspberrypi CRON[6668]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Aug 14 6:09:02      raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Clean php session files...
Aug 14 6:09:02      raspberrypi CRON[6674]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php/sessionclean ] && if [ ! -d /run/systemd/system ]
Aug 14 6:09:02      raspberrypi CRON[6668]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Aug 14 6:09:02      raspberrypi systemd[1]: phpsessionclean.service: Succeeded.
Aug 14 6:09:02      raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Clean php session files.
Aug 14 6:14:36      raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Daily apt upgrade and clean activities...
Aug 14 6:14:40      raspberrypi systemd[1]: apt-daily-upgrade.service: Succeeded.
Aug 14 6:14:40      raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Daily apt upgrade and clean activities.
Aug 14 6:17:01      raspberrypi CRON[11005]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Aug 14 6:17:01      raspberrypi CRON[11009]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Aug 14 6:17:01      raspberrypi CRON[11005]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Aug 14 6:25:01      raspberrypi CRON[15276]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Aug 14 6:25:01      raspberrypi CRON[15281]: (root) CMD (test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily )
Aug 14 6:25:02      raspberrypi CRON[15276]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
******* 06:32 FREEZE        
Aug 14 6:39:01      raspberrypi CRON[22772]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Aug 14 6:39:01      raspberrypi CRON[22777]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php/sessionclean ] && if [ ! -d /run/systemd/system ]
Aug 14 6:39:01      raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Clean php session files...
Aug 14 6:39:01      raspberrypi CRON[22772]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Aug 14 6:39:01      raspberrypi systemd[1]: phpsessionclean.service: Succeeded.
Aug 14 6:39:01      raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Clean php session files.
...

******* NOT FREEZING Aug 15     

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ journalctl --since "2019-08-16 06:00:00"     
Aug 16 6:09:01      raspberrypi CRON[13098]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Aug 16 6:09:01      raspberrypi CRON[13102]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php/sessionclean ] && if [ ! -d /run/systemd/system ]
Aug 16 6:09:01      raspberrypi CRON[13098]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Aug 16 6:09:03      raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Clean php session files...
Aug 16 6:09:04      raspberrypi systemd[1]: phpsessionclean.service: Succeeded.
Aug 16 6:09:04      raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Clean php session files.
Aug 16 6:17:01      raspberrypi CRON[21638]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Aug 16 6:17:01      raspberrypi CRON[21643]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Aug 16 6:17:01      raspberrypi CRON[21638]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
******* 06:31 FREEZE        
Aug 16 6:25:01      raspberrypi CRON[30176]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Aug 16 6:25:01      raspberrypi CRON[30182]: (root) CMD (test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily ))
Aug 16 6:25:02      raspberrypi CRON[30176]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Aug 16 6:39:01      raspberrypi CRON[12819]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Aug 16 6:39:01      raspberrypi CRON[12823]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php/sessionclean ] && if [ ! -d /run/systemd/system ]
Aug 16 6:39:01      raspberrypi CRON[12819]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Aug 16 6:39:03      raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Clean php session files...
Aug 16 6:39:04      raspberrypi systemd[1]: phpsessionclean.service: Succeeded.
Aug 16 6:39:04      raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Clean php session files.
Aug 16 6:41:03      raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Daily apt upgrade and clean activities...
Aug 16 6:41:06      raspberrypi systemd[1]: apt-daily-upgrade.service: Succeeded.
...
```

I have no problems with power to my Raspberry. I have tried to reinstall the system on a new fresh SD-card. I upgraded from stretch to buster. The problem remains...

This is driving my nuts! I can access my Raspberry Pi via XRDP. Neither the display nor Chromium are completely dead. What is causing the chrome GUI to stop updating? Why is this happening every morning round 06:30 AM??

Comment: There are two things going on in the log around that time.  There's nothing to indicate they have anything to do with it, but as a place to start, you could try disabling `rngd` (it runs once an hour, but is not particularly important unless you are doing important things encrypted over a network).  The other thing is `apt-daily-upgrade`, which you could try and temporarily disable.  Then those can at least be ruled out.  If you don't have it yet, you should add as much logging of your own as you can on both server and client side.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions! Unfortunately I am not successful in finding a way to disable rngd? And for trying something new regarding the crons. 'crontab -e' and 'sudo crontab -e' gives me no editable jobs.  I would like to try to shut them off completely on the Pi (temporarily). Is it a bad idea?

Comment: Neither of them are run via cron; they're init services.  One is `rng-tools`, the other `apt-daily-upgrade` and you can stop/disable them with `sudo systemctl stop ______` and `sudo systemctl disable ____`.  Again I doubt this is the source of your problems but you might as well rule it out.